# Laravel - cannot use Eloquent model method

Tags: php, database, laravel, eloquent

The table `distributor_requisition_items` has the columns :`requisition_id`,`product_id` ,`measuring_unit_id`,`quantity`

In the model `DistributorRequisition.php`, I have:

```
   class DistributorRequisition extends Model
    {

       public function items()
        {
            return  $this->belongsToMany('App\Product','distributor_requisition_items',
'requisition_id','product_id')->withPivot('measuring_unit_id','quantity');
        }


    }
```

In the controller I have :

```
    class CurrentInventoryController extends Controller
    {
            public function distributor_inventory(Request $request)
                {

                     $distributor_requisition=DistributorRequisition::get();

                     $distributor_requisitions_all= $distributor_requisition->items; 
// this line produces an error



                     return view('admin.current_inventory.distributor-inventory',
        compact('distributor_requisitions_all','stores',.....));

    }
    }
```

In the `distributor-inventory.blade.php`, I have :

```
    @foreach($distributor_requisitions_all as $aP)

      {{$aP->items->measuring_unit_id}}

    @endforeach
```

I get the following error :

**Exception in Collection.php line 1527: Property [items] does not exist on this collection instance.**

**in Collection.php line 1527 at Collection->__get('items') in CurrentInventoryController.php line 64**

And the line 64 in the controller has :
`$distributor_requisitions_all= $distributor_requisition->items;`

So how to use the eloquent model method `items` in the controller so that I can access the `distributor_requisitions_all` variable in the view to extract values from it ?

Answer (score 0):

`$distributor_requisition=DistributorRequisition::get();` is a collection of Model DistributorRequisition, while items is a method inside the model that is why it is giving you an error .. you can't directly call a Model method from a collection .. and to solve your issue what you have to do is

in your function

```
public function distributor_inventory(Request $request)
{
    $distributor_requisition=DistributorRequisition::get();
    return view('admin.current_inventory.distributor-inventory',
    compact('distributor_requisition','stores',.....));
}
```

and in your view

```
@foreach($distributor_requisition as $aP)

    // {{ $aP->items->measuring_unit_id }}
    // that will give you error since $aP->items is another collection of many model item what you can do is add another loop

    @foreach($aP->items as $item)
        $item->pivot->measuring_unit_id }}
    @endforeach

@endforeach
```

Comment: I got the error : `ErrorException in Collection.php line 1527: Property [measuring_unit_id] does not exist on this collection instance. (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\celero\resources\views\admin\current_inventory\distributor-inventory.blade.php)

    in Collection.php line 1527`

Comment: do you have that field in `distributor_requisition_items` table ?

Comment: yes I have that field in the `distributor_requisition_items` table ?

Comment: have you tried `$aP->items->pivot->measuring_unit_id` ?

Comment: hope it helped .. :)

Comment: got this : Property [pivot] does not exist on this collection instance.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145085/discussion-between-istiaque-ahmed-and-demonyowh).

Comment: updated my answer to resolve your issue .. happy coding

Comment: hmm, the wrong code should be commented in your answer

Answer (score 0):

use with() method instead of get().

```
public function distributor_inventory(Request $request)
{
    $distributor_requisition=DistributorRequisition::with('items');
    return view('admin.current_inventory.distributor-inventory', ['distributor_requisitions_all' => $distributor_requisition]);
}
```

Comment: in FF, the page just goes blank and Chrome says `This page isn’t working

localhost is currently unable to handle this request.
HTTP ERROR 500`  .

Comment: okay just make it dd($distributor_requisition) and let me know the result.

Comment: where to make that ?

Comment: Under this line ` $distributor_requisition=DistributorRequisition::with('items');`
dd($distributor_requisition)

Comment: This is what I got : `Builder {#498 ▼
  #query: Builder {#490 ▶}
  #model: DistributorRequisition {#493 ▶}
  #eagerLoad: array:1 [▶]
  #localMacros: []
  #onDelete: null
  #passthru: array:11 [▶]
  #scopes: []
  #removedScopes: []
}`

Comment: Click on all black icon and it will expose all value. So share a screenshot

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145086/discussion-between-istiaque-ahmed-and-sumon-mahmud).